# Outdoor plant identification - long horizontal roots

Tags: identification

Can anyone identify this plant? They seem to like to grow on our driveway area, which is pretty sandy earth, and sparsely covered with grass. I don't think they grow very tall, but seem to form in a line linked together by a long horizontal root. This is about 100km north of Ottawa, Canada.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know the name of your plant, but I do know that those long horizontal roots which propagate new plants are called **runners** by horticulturalists and [stolons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolon) by botanists. That might help you find out more.